# How do I view Java strings in the Eclipse debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to view the value of a String variable at a breakpoint while developing in Java with Eclipse.

The String variable is displayed as `[47, 110, 109, 107, 111]`, which makes sense since a string is really an array of ASCII characters.

However, I'd prefer to not have to convert from ASCII values to characters every time I examine a string. How can I have the debugger display the string as opposed to an array of ASCII values?

Comment: It should be there, right next to the variable name in `"`s.

Comment: Not for me. Eclipse just gives me `(id=95)` to the right of the variable name.

Comment: My Eclipse debugger has always shown the String value in double quotes next to the id. Are you using the Variable view in the Debug Perspective? If not what view and perspective? Also, whenever I click on the variable in the source code at a breakpoint, Eclipse pops up what looks like a tooltip with the value (when its running and stopped at the break point)

Comment: Are you confident that your variable is a String? Can you add the actual code for the variable?

Comment: A quick workaround would be to select the variable and press `Ctrl + Shift + D, D`

Comment: This is very interesting. Could you please post a snapshot of the Variables view with the annoyance you mentioned in your post ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting your array to a `string` with the correct encoding by creating a new insatnce of the string object:

```
String s = new String(bytes,"ASCII");
System.out.println(s);
```

Here is a short example to demonstrate:

```
    String example = "This is an example";
    byte[] bytes = example.getBytes();

    System.out.println("Text : " + example);
    System.out.println("Text [Byte Format] : " + bytes);
    System.out.println("Text [Byte Format] : " + bytes.toString());

    String s = null;
    try {
        s = new String(bytes, "ASCII");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println("Text from bytes: " + s);
```

output:

> Text : This is an example
>
> Text [Byte Format] : [B@187aeca
>
> Text [Byte Format] : [B@187aeca
>
> Text from bytes: This is an example

**References:**

- http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-byte-array-to-string-in-java/

Comment: Thank you, where do I type this into? The main control flow or is there a "console" window into which I can insert java snippets?

Comment: You should be able to evaluate an expression.

Comment: @DavidFaux depends on where you are outputting your byte array contents I guess? see edited post

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure your variable is a String:

[image: MyString]

The the debug view should automatically display it as a string.

[image: DebugView]

Make sure your variable is indeed a String.

Answer (score -1):

i have been in that situation before.
I assume the problem occured upon the eclipse version while you were debugging.
After changing to older version of eclipse or IntelliJ (2018) and jdk 8 => The Problem solved.